# Who are the tarks and what power do they have regarding the Watchers?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In *Return of the King*, Book VI, chapter 1 "The Tower of Cirith Ungol," in the discussion between the orcs Snaga and Shagrat, the former states (unknowingly referring to Sam):

> Gorbag was right, I tell you. There's a great fighter about, one of those bloody-handed Elves, or one of the filthy *tarks*. He's coming here, I tell you. You heard the bell. He's got past the Watchers, and that's *tark's* work.

**Of whom does Snaga speak, when he mentions *tarks*? And what power does a *tark* have to get *past* the Watchers?**

The Watchers are described earlier in the chapter, and I assume Snaga means "got past" yet sound the alarm, since clearly the orcs get past the Watchers also. Snaga is obviously fearful that a person of great power is inside the fortress.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Tark* is a word in the Orcish-Westron [pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin); it refers to a Gondorian human:

> In this jargon *tark*, 'man of Gondor', was a debased form of *tarkil*, a Quenya word used in Westron for one of Númenorean descent.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix F I "The Languages and Peoples of the Third Age" Of Other Races</sup>

Snaga assumes, not entirely incorrectly, that only an Elf or a Númenórean would have the power to bypass the Watchers.

Although there's no evidence that they actually *have* any especial power to do so<sup>1</sup>, there's ample reason for Snaga to *believe* them capable:

- Númenor/Gondor has historically been closely allied with the Elves, the most magically-advanced race in Middle-earth
- The Gondorians are descended from the only armies to ever defeat Sauron: the Númenórean armies of Tar-Minastir, who routed Sauron's forces during his first expansion across Middle-earth; the Gondorian armies of Elendil, from the Last Alliance; and the Gondorian armies of Eärnur, who (admittedly with Elvish assistance) drove the Witch-King out of the North.

  We know that modern Orcs [have knowledge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92785/31051) of the Siege of Barad-dûr, so it's not a stretch to imagine that the descendants of Númenor have built up a reputation in the minds of the armies of Mordor
- It's [possible](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21501/31051) that the Watchers were built (at least partially) by Gondorians at the same time as the Tower itself<sup>2</sup>; if so (or if the Orcs believe that to be so), then it's not unreasonable for Snaga to assume that a Gondorian would know of some weakness in their construction

---

<sup>1</sup> We don't actually know a whole lot about the Watchers at all, so it's not entirely clear by what mechanism (other than Galadriel's Phial, of course) they even *could* be bypassed

<sup>2</sup> Personally, I don't find this likely. But then, it's about what Snaga believes, not what I believe

Comment: But _how_ would they get past? Not just that they have the "power" to, but is it by merely force of will to walk past, or use of magic (similar to Sam's), or total avoidance of having to pass the Watchers by some other means? Is there any description of the Númenórean power that would indicate how they might have bypass the Watchers, that is, what Snaga was thinking about their ability to do so (it is interesting that his statement only mentions the passing as "_tark's_ work," not that also of elves, though in context that would seem implied)?

Comment: Your edit came in as I was commenting... :-). That addition is helpful as a plausible analysis.

Comment: @ScottS I've also seen it argued ([by Michael Martinez](http://middle-earth.xenite.org/2012/07/25/what-are-the-silent-watchers-of-mordor/), for example) that "that's *tark*'s work" refers to the construction of the Watchers rather than bypassing them. I'm not sure I agree with that reading, but it would explain why a Gondorian could bypass them

Comment: @ScottS It doesn't matter *how* they get past or *whether* they could get past, just that the Orcs believe they could. Gondorians could do many powerful things, so it's likely Orcs would believe it.

Comment: Just my two cents worth, but I would point out that Aragorn (by far the most powerful Númenórean of the Third Age) was able to wrest control of a palantír from Sauron himself. With this in mind, one could see why the Orcs would assume, if it was a Man, it would have to be a Númenórean.

Comment: @BobbyNewmark Aragorn was strengthened in that encounter because he was the rightful owner of the *palantír*; that's a rather special case

Comment: So Snaga's comment was rather along the lines of some American soldiers in an alien invasion film looking at a flying saucer and saying "Holy crap! Must be the Russians!"

Comment: @JasonBaker, I get that the palantír was a special case, I just feel that it's a canonical example of why a Númenórean (Tark) could get past the watchers. Since Snaga was at the Siege of Barad-dûr at the end of the second age, he would have some idea of their old powers.

Comment: Also worth noting that "magic" and "force of will" are largely the same thing in LoTR.